# How to add gradient color to VectorDrawable in android?

Tags: android, vector, gradient, android-vectordrawable

I have a vector like this:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="375dp"
android:height="156dp"
android:viewportHeight="120"
android:viewportWidth="190">

<path
    android:fillColor="#213368"
    android:pathData=" M 0,0 L 0,156 L 375,156 L 300,50z" />
```

I need to add a gradient color instead the fill color to this vector. What is the best way?

Comment: Please refer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40872114/can-gradientcolor-be-used-to-define-a-gradient-for-a-fill-or-stroke-entirely-in