# Vector drawable with gradient color not supporting below API 24

Tags: android, android-drawable

Vector drawable of image contains `Gradient` colors, which are not showing in `imageview` for below API version of 24, i am using **Android-Studio 3.1**

*ic_gradient_image.xml :*

```
<aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
         <gradient android:endX="270.1115" android:endY="1.3445"
              android:startX="243.3148" android:startY="512.6555" android:type="linear">
               <item android:color="#FFFF9426" android:offset="0"/>
               <item android:color="#FF9D6936" android:offset="0.4076"/>
               <item android:color="#FF404146" android:offset="0.8154"/>
               <item android:color="#FF1B314C" android:offset="1"/>
          </gradient>
  </aapt:attr>
```

Above `xml` shows,

> Attribute `endX` is only used in API level 24 and higher.
>
> Attribute `endY` is only used in API level 24 and higher.
>
> Attribute `offset` is only used in API level 24 and higher.

*build.gradle :*

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

*Application.java :*

```
static
{
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}
```

*Implemented in adapter :*

```
holder.product_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_gradient_image);
```

Also tried,

```
holder.product_imageButton.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_gradient_image));
```

I have tried [Solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40872114/can-gradientcolor-be-used-to-define-a-gradient-for-a-fill-or-stroke-entirely-in) and [Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854772/vectordrawable-invalid-drawable-tag-gradient)

Is there any way to reflect `gradient` colors in `imageview` under API 23 with Android Studio 3.0.

Comment: Can you found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54683616/2960387

add this inside your `build.gradle`:

```
defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

use `app:srcCompat` instead of `android:src` on ImageView

use `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton` instead of an `ImageButton` if you want this for an `ImageButton`